# Why doesn't calling a substring using the length of the string as the beginning index throw an OutOfBoundsException?

Tags: java

When was testing some code, I noticed that the substring method wouldn't throw an exception if the index I used was equal to the length of the string. For example:

```
String s = "holy";
System.out.println(s.substring(4));
```

The output would return nothing, but it wouldn't throw an exception. But if I tried to call:

```
String s = "holy";
System.out.println(s.substring(5));
```

It would throw an IndexOutOfBoundsException. I read the Javadoc for the method and it says

> if beginIndex is negative or larger than the length of this String object.

Anyone know why it allows for the beginning index to be equal to the string length?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Think about other invocations of `substring`:

```
"holy".substring(n)
```

can be visualized as copying the range of characters between `n` (inclusive) and the end of the string (exclusive).

For example:

```
"holy".substring(0)`

 h o l y
O-------X    (O = start, X = end)
0 1 2 3 4
```

That is, the start position is just before the character, and the end position is just after the character. The resulting length of the string is `end - start`, 4 in this case.

and

```
"holy".substring(1)

 h o l y
  O-----X     // length = 4 - 1 = 3.
0 1 2 3 4
```

etc. Then:

```
"holy".substring(4)
```

can be visualized as

```
 h o l y
        O     // O and X are at the same position
        X     // length = 4 - 4 = 0
0 1 2 3 4
```

It's fine that O and X are at the same position: it just means the result is a zero-length string, `""`.

But, increase the index to 5:

```
"holy".substring(5)

 h o l y
        X-O    // O is after X
               // length = 4 - 5 = -1 (?!)
0 1 2 3 4 5
```

A string of length -1 doesn't make sense, hence the exception.

Comment: Thanks, the visualization helped a lot, and it makes sense now

Answer (score 1):

There is basically one reason for this, in `substring(int beginIndex, int endIndex)`, if `beginIndex == endIndex` then the result is an empty string. So given that property, and the fact that the maximum value of `endIndex` is the string length, then allowing `string.substring(string.length(), string.length())` should be allowed and return an empty string as well. And this last can be simplified to `string.substring(string.length())`.

Allowing the length as a valid begin index also provides a number of nice properties:

- `"".substring(0)` returns `""`
- Considering the pairs `String start = string.substring(0, n)` and `String end = string.substring(n)` results in the following:

  - `n = 0`: `start = ""`, `end = string`
  - `n = string.length()`: `start = string`, `end = ""`

Disallowing this and throwing an exception would require all kinds of additional bounds checks in string manipulation code (and in substring itself for that matter).

Answer (score 0):

- public String substring(int startIndex) return the substring from the startIndex of your string. So in your example it will be position 4 (which is exists) and the substring will be "" (empty string).

Comment: What's really going on "under the hood"? Position 4 is technically outside the index range of the string, so how is it possible to return something without throwing an error?